# How to horizontally scroll between pages of controls in UIScrollView iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to find the way to implement a scroll view on my viewController screen, which allows the user to scroll between different pages of controls and have the controls around it, outside the scroll view, react to whatever data or actions take place in the scroll view.

All the tutorials I have found is adding a scroll view that shows a carousel of images, or programmatically adding coloured frames. Very little control interaction.

But none that shows how to create 2-3 pages of controls (buttons and labels), and how to integrate it with the parent view (so the parent view and scroll view talk to each other in one view).

So for now, what would be the first step to create a scroll view with 2 'pages' of controls? Has anyone come across any good resources for this? How is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Scroll View. Add top,left,right, bottom constraint to scroll view. Set horizontal only in storyboard.
2. Add a view inside scroll view. Now add height constraint from this view to super view. (Not the scroll view.) Specify some width and add width constraint. 
   I suggest you to use [UIPageViewController](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/) for this type of scrolling.

Comment: Thank Saqib for your reply.
So ive added the scroll view. I think I have the constraints sorted there.
I then added a 'View' inside the scroll view. Constraints are a bit trickier to get right, but that's a small part of my challenge.

So now, I am still a little clueless on how to now add my two 'pages' of controls to this view. Where does the UIPageViewController come into play?

Do I create my my pages of controls on this View itself, or do I have add another viewcontroller to the storyboard, and somehow link it to that?
Sorry for all the questions, just trying to understand 100%.:) Thanks!

Comment: I have added a link to UIPageViewController tutorial in previous answer. There are two ways in which you can achieve what you are trying to do. One is UIScrollView. Other one is UIPageView. To use UIPageView follow that tutorial.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. I misunderstood your answer and thought it was suggested to use both the scrollView and pageview, and the linked tutorial didn't seem to cover the scrollView part.
Will look at the tutorial again and see if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go for UICollectionViewLayout and enable paging to true. Using this will give you the finest control of each page and the horizontal as well as vertical scroll.